# Bootstrap modal backdrop issue with Isotope

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I'm using ISOTOPE to show some boxes with basic information.

Whenever I want to show more details I use jQuery to call a bootstrap modal.

The problem is when the modal hides.

After the modal hides, if I apply a filter on ISOTOPE, there is an ugly black path (Windows style) wherever the animated Isotope boxes move.

Any ideas why?

If this is hard to figure out I can upload a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having no opinions, solutions nor comments I'll post my own findings.

I'm avoiding this behavior just by reloading all Isotope items using the following method:

```
         $('.grid').isotope( 'reloadItems' );
```